# What is the best implementation of an HTTP client in Android to consume a web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I have the following RESTful code which reaches out to this web service and posts a value and gets a return. The code works, however as you can see it is located in the MainActivity in the onCreate() method. I shouldn't have to go into details to explain that this is a bad practice. So, what should I do in order to place this code in order to have the app have the best performance and doesn't crash. I guess what I'm looking for is something like a design pattern in order to implement the most robust application using HTTPClient to consume a web service. thanks

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit");
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Celsius", "77"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String page = sb.toString();
        // Log.i(tag, page);
        System.out.println(page);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You might want to put that code into an AsyncTask so the app performance on starting would not be affected. I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would place it in a class and setup everything in its constructor and call its methods from the activity.